# Replace all instances of \ with /

Tags: c++, strings

My main goal is to perform the conversion on a list of strings. Is this a sensible approach or should I refactor?

Please note that I cannot use Boost in my work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>


char fix_delim(char ch) {
    return ch == '\\' ? '/' : ch;
}

std::string& fix_str(std::string& str) {
   std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), fix_delim);
   return str;
}

int main() {
   std::list<std::string> files;
   files.push_back("folder\\file1");
   files.push_back("folder\\file2");

   //simple example of fix_delim
   std::string one("folder\\file1");
   std::transform(one.begin(), one.end(), one.begin(), fix_delim);

   //Is this a good way to solve this problem of replacing all instances of \ with / in a list of strings?
   std::transform(files.begin(), files.end(), files.begin(), fix_str);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++11 you can use lambda, otherwise make the helper function static.

If you're tied to std::string and no stock solution, this one is about as good as it gets. I suggest naming it properly like fix_path_separators or along the lines describing its *purpose*.

Answer (score 8):

Seems to me that the right algorithm for this job is `std::replace`:

```
std::replace(input.begin(), input.end(), '\\', '/');
```

The easiest way to apply to a collection of strings is probably to use `std::for_each` with a lambda:

```
std::for_each(files.begin(), files.end(), 
              [](std::string &s) { std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), '\\', '/'); });
```

If you can't use a lambda, you can write a tiny function object instead:

```
class path_dos2unix {
    void operator()(std::string &s) {  
        std::replace(s.begin(), s.end(), '\\', '/');
    }
};
```

...and then invoke that:

```
std::for_each(files.begin(), files.end(), path_dos2unix());
```

Comment: In our work, with multiple platforms to support and waiting for other depts to upgrade it will be a long time till we can use lambdas.  But I would love to be able to.